# JQuery sticky bar flickering on page resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've added a sticky 'call to action' bar to my site, it works like a sticky navigation, however it's stuck to the bottom of the window its original position in the page is scrolled past, then it jumps back in to the flow of the document.

It uses a CSS class '.sticky' to add the fixed position when the scroll position is less than the vertical position of the bar's original position.

The issue is, when I resize the page I get a nasty flicker and the bar more often than not disappears from view.

The code I am using is below...

```
(function() {

    $(window).on('resize', function() {  

        var stickyNavTop = $('#wrap-bar').offset().top; 

        var stickyNav = function(){

            var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - $('.cta-bar').height();

            if (scrollBottom < stickyNavTop) {   
                $('#wrap-bar').addClass('sticky');
                $('#wrap-bar-dummy').show();
            } else {  
                $('#wrap-bar').removeClass('sticky');
                $('#wrap-bar-dummy').hide();
            }   

        };  

        stickyNav();  

        $(window).scroll(function() {  
            stickyNav();
        });

    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I need to change to get the bar to stop flickering when resizing?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a weird idea but can you make the #wrap-bar position absolute and then bottom:0 with CSS? No jQuery needed then?

Comment: I need the jQuery as I want the bar to jump back into the flow of the page when the page becomes a different section. For example the call to action isn't relevant when the form or footer are in view.

Comment: I think you can do this with using CSS. Then if the bar is reaching a certain anchor you can use jQuery to hold the bar to the anchor position.

Answer (score 0):

The flickering you're reporting is most likely because Javascript isn't rendering your DOM changes as quickly as you scroll. As mentioned by @Switching Brains, attempt using CSS to absolutely position your footer at 0px from the bottom of the window. Then, you'll only need Javascript to locate when you've reached the bottom of the page, then apply your class to hold it in a fixed position.

Comment: It doesn't flicker on scroll, only on resize.
I don't require the bar to show at the bottom of the page, and absolute positioning would only achieve this if the parent elements didn't have position values. Using a css 'fixed' position would lock it to the bottom of the page, which is what the 'sticky' class does. Until the original position of the div is scrolled past and then it is removed.

Answer (score 0):

A realy dirty example of this, but you'll get the idea:

HTML

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="bar">Bar at the bottom</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 html, body {
    height:100%;
    widht:100%;
}

#body {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}

#bar {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:20px;
    width:300px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px;
    background-color:#cccccc;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Auc6n/

Comment: This is not what I'm looking to achieve, please have a look at the example here... http://www.haydockoffice.co.uk/crm/green-deal.html . I don't want the bar to be permanently fixed to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found with Mozilla that .resize() caused a lot of page flickering as it was being driven too hard.

I used:

```
 $window.resize(throttle(500,function(){
```